# Nullable warnings with JObject and SelectToken in c#

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I'm getting these warnings with the code below:

CS8601 - Possible null reference assignment.

CS8604 - Possible null reference argument for parameter.

I understand the nullable concept and have read many posts about it (and this project does have Nullable enabled in PropertyGroup).

However, when it comes to JObject and SelectToken, I didn't found anything that resolves the green squigglies (one is js.IsNullOrEmpty... and the other is js.SelectToken("stuff.result...)

```
    string[] mystring;

    string responseBody = DataString.mydata;
                
    var js = (JObject?)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

    bool empty = js.IsNullOrEmpty();
    
    if (!empty)
    {
        mystring[1] = js.SelectToken("stuff.result[0].meta.data").Value<string>();
    }
```

DataString is a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the ? from (JObject?) or do this:

```
    string responseBody = DataString.mydata;
                
    var js = (JObject?)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

    var empty = js?.IsNullOrEmpty();
    
    if (empty == false)
    {
        mystring[1] = js.SelectToken("stuff.result[0].meta.data", true).Value<string>();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but removing ? from JObject just adds a warning to that line (doesn't remove it from the mystring line). 

For the other suggestion, I did try something similar with a bool and IsNullOrEmpty. I also just tried exactly what you suggested and it's still showing the warning.

Comment: I corrected the answer. The mystring statement as you have it will throw a null exception if the JSON path you specified is not found. Passing in true makes it throw an exception instead of returning null.

Comment: I tried those corrections but am getting the same result. I wonder if any other code is influencing these.